# Showpare 6 can't register custom cms-elements

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I used the "Shopware 6 Toolbox" plugin for creating a custom cms element.

When I add my custom cms-block with my custom cms-element I get the following warnings:

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did
> you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make
> sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> ---> < SwCmsBlockGalleryInfobox >
> < SwCmsBlock >
> < SwCmsSection >
> < SwPage >
> < SwCmsDetail >
> < SwErrorBoundary>
> < SwDesktop>
> < SwAdmin>
> < Root>

and

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "element"
>
> found in
>
> ---> < SwCmsElComponentInfoBox>
> < SwCmsBlockGalleryInfobox>
> < SwCmsBlock>
> < SwCmsSection>
> < SwPage>
> < SwCmsDetail>
> < SwErrorBoundary>
> < SwDesktop>
> < SwAdmin>
> < Root>

I compared all index.js with those from the [tutorial](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element) and didn't find any difference. Does anyone knows why I get this warning?

I also get an error:

> An error was captured in current module: TypeError: Cannot set
> properties of undefined (setting 'config')
> at VueComponent.initElementConfig (sw-cms-element.mixin.js?7948:64:13)
> at VueComponent.createdComponent (index.js?7f82:19:18)
> at VueComponent.created (index.js?7f82:14:14)
> at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.esm.js?a026:1872:1)
> at callHook (vue.esm.js?a026:4244:1)
> at Vue._init (vue.esm.js?a026:5031:1)
> at new VueComponent (vue.esm.js?a026:5177:1)
> at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.esm.js?a026:3313:1)
> at init (vue.esm.js?a026:3142:1)
> at createComponent (vue.esm.js?a026:6033:1)

I haven't customized the generated cms-element, so there is nothing to configure. Now I'm asking myself why I get this error. Can anybody answer my question?

---

Here's the code

```
plugins/ProductInfoBox/src/Resources/app/administration/src/main.js

import './module/sw-cms/blocks/commerce/gallery-infobox';
import './module/sw-cms/elements/info-box';
```

```
plugins/ProductInfoBox/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/
info-box/index.js

import './component';
import './config';
import './preview';

Shopware.Service('cmsService').registerCmsElement({
    name: 'info-box',
    label: 'sw-cms.elements.info-box.label',
    component: 'sw-cms-el-component-info-box',
    configComponent: 'sw-cms-el-config-info-box',
    previewComponent: 'sw-cms-el-preview-info-box',
    defaultConfig: {
        content: {
            source: 'static',
            value: `
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
                sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
                Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
                Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            `.trim(),
        },
        verticalAlign: {
            source: 'static',
            value: null,
        },
    },
    defaultData: {}
});
```

```
plugins/ProductInfoBox/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/
info-box/component/index.js

import template from './sw-cms-el-component-info-box.html.twig';
import './sw-cms-el-component-info-box.scss';

const {Component, Mixin} = Shopware;

Component.register('sw-cms-el-component-info-box', {
    template,

    mixins: [
        Mixin.getByName('cms-element')
    ],

    computed: {
        getText(){
            return this.element.config.content.value;
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    methods: {
        createdComponent() {
            this.initElementConfig('info-box');
            this.initElementData('info-box');
        },
    },
});
```

```
plugins/ProductInfoBox/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/info-box/config/index.js

import template from './sw-cms-el-config-info-box.html.twig';
import './sw-cms-el-config-info-box.scss';

const {Component, Mixin} = Shopware;

Component.register('sw-cms-el-config-info-box', {
    template,

    inject: ['repositoryFactory'],

    mixins: [
        Mixin.getByName('cms-element')
    ],

    computed: {
        getText(){
            return this.element.config.content.value;
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    methods: {
        createdComponent() {
            this.initElementConfig('info-box');
        },

    },
});
```

```
plugins/ProductInfoBox/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/
info-box/preview/index.js

import template from './sw-cms-el-preview-info-box.html.twig';
import './sw-cms-el-preview-info-box.scss';

const {Component} = Shopware;

Component.register('sw-cms-el-preview-info-box', {
    template
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new components aren't registered. Given you made sure they were generated correctly and are imported in the `main.js`, did you [build the administration](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-module#build-the-administration) afterwards? Once this has been done you can reload the administration in the browser and the components should be registered.

Comment: I imported all my components in the main.js and ran build-administration. Afterwards I used the administration watcher.

I'm still getting those messages

Comment: I just noticed that these messages only appear when using the watcher

Comment: I just get that error

Comment: So when using build-administration it works? Is it a problem with the watcher? If so, your (new) question would be more like "CMS elements are not registered when using watch-administration.sh"

Comment: I don't think that's it because the error message is still given. So I think that my custom cms-element is still not registered

Answer (score 1):

small self-promotion ;-)

If you like a simpler approach to create own cms elements, check out our plugin "CmsElementBuilder"
https://store.shopware.com/en/neti984871281616/create-content-elements-for-shopping-experience-cmselementbuilder.html

Its very simple to create cms elements via config.

Here youll find a simple boilerplate plugin with some predefinded elements:
https://gitlab.netinventors.de/shopware6/labs/NetiNextCmsElementBuilderDemo

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a typo in my component twig file